# CSV.vim how to change the column separator?

Tags: plugin-csv

I am using [csv.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim) and I would like to change the column separator from semicolon to comma.

**How can I change the column separator with CSV.vim?**

Comment: I spend a lot of time and effort on the documentation. Did you actually read it and try to find the answer there?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I hope you mind others to ask questions about csv.vim.

Comment: I don't mind asking questions about csv.vim, in fact I am always trying to help with my plugin. However when asking questions one should at least show, that the available documentation has been read. After all, that's what it is for ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution

```
:NewDelimiter ,
```

Comment: this changes the current detected delimiter to a comma